# If you get invited to share a Google Play Android Developer Console then How to add the application to the console of admin which sent you a invite.?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

My client sent me a invite to my google account to share Google Play Developer Consoleto add his app on his console.I received an email from google regarding this .But after accepting invitation where I add the application so that the app which i add should be added on my client console.
I did not have the credentials of my client account.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Developer Console, which SO is not the support of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He can give you different permissions. There is only 1 console, it is not separated for you or him.
You need to ask him, to give you some the following permissions, depends what he/you want to do:

1. Create and edit application drafts
2. Editing APK
3. Editing APK in alpha and beta
4. Editing games
5. Publishing games

Comment: how do you choose the account which publishes the app?

Comment: Go to android Developer Console, in the upper right corner you can choose your account (if you have multiple). Then on the left panel you have settings -> user accounts & rights -> invite new user. You can then click on individual permissions that you want to add to user.